# Can anyone tell why my test won't run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm at the very end of chapter 9 in the Rails Tutorial and this chapter has been kicking my ass. I just to get these test to run (and pass) and I can move on to chapter 10. Any help would be appreciated.

```
rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:155: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

is what I'm getting when trying to run the tests, I know this means I am missing an end somewhere but when I add an end to the end it asks for another, then another, then it says I'm missing an end in user_pages.spec Then I add the fix the end there and get about 19 errors. Anyways here is my code.

authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

 describe "signin" do
  before { visit signin_path }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    before { click_button "Sign in" }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

  describe "after visiting another page" do
    before { click_link "Home" }
    it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
  end



  describe "with valid information" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

  it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
  it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }

  it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
    end
   end
  end

describe "authorization" do

 describe "for non-signed-in users" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
    before do
      visit edit_user_path(user)
      fill_in "Email", with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end

    describe "after signing in" do

      it "should render the desired protected page" do
        page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
      end

      describe "when signing in again" do
        before do
          delete signout_path
          visit signin_path
          fill_in "Email", with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it "should render the default (profile) page" do
          page.should have_selector('title', text: user.name)
        end
      end
     end
   end

 describe "in the Users controller" do

 describe "visiting the edit page" do
  before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

describe "submitting to the update action" do
  before { put user_path(user) }
  specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
end

describe "visiting the user index" do
  before { visit users_path }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

 end




describe "as wrong user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
    before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
    it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
    before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
  end
 end


describe "as non-admin user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before { sign_in non_admin }

  describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
    before { delete user_path(user) }
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }        
    end
    end
  end

  end
```

here is my user_pages_spec.rb:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "index" do

 let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

 before(:each) do
  sign_in user
  visit users_path
 end

it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All users') }

describe "pagination" do

  before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
  after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

  it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

  it "should list each user" do
    User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
      page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
    end
   end
  end
 end

describe "delete links" do

  it { should_not have_link('delete') }

  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before do
      sign_in admin
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
    end
  end
end

describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { visit user_path(user) }

it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end

describe "signup page" do
before { visit signup_path }

it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
     expect { click_button "Create my account" }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end

describe "error messages" do
before { click_button "Create my account" }

 it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
 it { should have_content('error') }
 end
end

describe "with valid information" do
before do
  fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
  fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
  fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
  fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
 end

it "should create a user" do
expect do
  click_button "Create my account"
 end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
end

describe "after saving the user" do
 before { click_button "Create my account" }
 let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

 it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
 it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
 it { should have_link('Sign out') }
  end
 end
end

describe "signup page" do
before { visit signup_path }

 it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
 it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "signup" do

before { visit signup_path }

let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
 end

 describe "with valid information" do
  before do
   fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
   fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
   fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
   fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
 end

it "should create a user" do
 expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
end
describe "edit" do
 let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
 before do
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user)
 end

 describe "page" do
  it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
 end

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Save changes" }

  it { should have_content('error') }
  end

 describe "with valid information" do
  let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
  let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
  before do
    fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
    fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
    fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
    fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Save changes"
  end

  it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
  it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
  it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
  specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
  specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
  end
 end
 end
 end
 end
```

here are my errors:

```
   Failures:

 1) User pages delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
    Failure/Error: expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    Capybara::ElementNotFound:
      no link with title, id or text 'delete' found
    # (eval):2:in `click_link'
    # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
    # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages delete links as an admin user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
      expected link "delete" to return something
   # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

 3) signup page 
   Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
   expected css "h1" with text "Sign up" to return something
   # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

 4) signup page 
   Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
    expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign up" to return  something
  # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) profile page 
   Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
     expected css "h1" with text "Person 38" to return something
  # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

6) profile page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
   expected css "title" with text "Person 39" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) signup page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
   expected css "h1" with text "Sign up" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

8) signup page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
   expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign up" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:115:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

9) signup with valid information edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
   expected css "title" with text "New Name" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:171:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

10) signup with valid information edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:173:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

11) signup with valid information edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
   expected css "div.alert.alert-success" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:172:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

12) signup with valid information edit with invalid information 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_content('error') }
   expected there to be content "error" in "with invalid information"
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:157:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

13) signup with valid information edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
   expected link "change" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:151:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

14) signup with valid information edit page 
  Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
   expected css "title" with text "Edit user" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:150:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

15) signup with valid information edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
   expected css "h1" with text "Update your profile" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:149:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

16) signup with invalid information error messages 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
   expected css "title" with text "Sign up" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

17) signup with valid information after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:106:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

18) signup with valid information after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
   expected css "div.alert.alert-success" with text "Welcome" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:105:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

19) signup with valid information after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
   expected css "title" with text "Example User" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:104:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 2.39 seconds
87 examples, 19 failures

Failed examples:

```
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:46 # User pages delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45 # User pages delete links as an admin user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:65 # signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:66 # signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58 # profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:59 # profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:114 # signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:115 # signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:171 # signup with valid information edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:173 # signup with valid information edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:172 # signup with valid information edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:157 # signup with valid information edit with invalid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:151 # signup with valid information edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:150 # signup with valid information edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:149 # signup with valid information edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:81 # signup with invalid information error messages 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:106 # signup with valid information after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:105 # signup with valid information after saving the user
```

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:104 # signup with valid information after saving the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had an extra end after the pagination block so I removed it and added to the end All tests passing now. Those green dots never looked so good.

Comment: That's great you solved your own problem!  Please accept your answer for everyone's reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder I tried to earlier but it makes you wait 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

Right. U missed 2 `end` in the authentication_pages_spec. And there's one extra `end` in the user_pages_spec. Put (or remove) these ends in the end of the files and that should do. I suggest using some good editor for your coding. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91445/best-ide-for-ruby-on-rails.

Comment: Ok, so I did that and have the tests failing with the 19 errors again. Would you mind looking at these errors and see if you can point me in the right direction? Thanks  also I'm using Sublime so I think my editor is good but my debugging skills suck... I'll add my errors above